# Android FragmentPagerAdapter display moredata

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager, 
I have to display more data in two fragments, but it does not show anything.

Is There an alternative layout to do it?

**this is layout code:**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+id/mainContent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1.8">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**this is adapter:**

```
public class HitoeAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private static HitoeAdapter adapter;
private final HeartRateFragment mHeartRateFragment;
private final ECGFragment mECGFragment;

public HitoeAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    mHeartRateFragment = new HeartRateFragment();
    mECGFragment = new ECGFragment();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            return mHeartRateFragment;
        case 1:
            return mECGFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: **more data in two fragments** means?

Comment: Yes, I have to display more data(heart rate, stress livel) dinamically in two fragment(in two different view) using viewPager, but it doesn't work.

Comment: your two different fragment has two different classes. And you can do anything in those classes like api call, data binding, etc.

Comment: Yes, I know, do you understand my problem? I have to display data in vtwo fragments by view pager, but nothing appears. Do you know how I can fix it? Or exist an alternative view?

Answer (score 0):

Create the adapter class like below--

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
```

}

Now add this method to set your fragments with viewpager -

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new HeartRateFragment(), "HeartRateFrag");
    adapter.addFragment(new ECGFragment(), "ECGFragment");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, have I call setupViewPager in activity class? Where i instance adapter class?

Comment: yes. from the activity class, initiate the viewpager with findviewbyid like --                    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

Comment: No it doesn't work, is there alternative layout to viewPager?

Comment: just keep the viewpager in your activity layout